# EXCEL: SUMPRODUCTS with operator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to include an operator in a SUMPRODUCTS formula, however I keep getting a #VALUE error. I am trying to divide by a value instead of multiple by it. For example instead of multiple by 3, I want to multiply by 1/3.

The following formula works perfectly:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!J:J="Example")+0;('Sheet1'!M:M=F$73)+0;'Sheet1'!G:G;'Sheet1'!N:N;INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q>=$A74);INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q<=EOMONTH($A74;0));'Sheet1'!K:K)
```

However, once I attempt to divide by column K instead of multiplying, I get the error. I tried to following formulas:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!J:J="Example")+0;('Sheet1'!M:M=F$73)+0;'Sheet1'!G:G;'Sheet1'!N:N;INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q>=$A74);INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q<=EOMONTH($A74;0));MINVERSE('Sheet1'!K:K))

= SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!J:J="Example")+0;('Sheet1'!M:M=F$73)+0;'Sheet1'!G:G;'Sheet1'!N:N;INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q>=$A74);INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q<=EOMONTH($A74;0));('Sheet1'!K:K)^-1)

= SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!J:J="Example")+0;('Sheet1'!M:M=F$73)+0;'Sheet1'!G:G;'Sheet1'!N:N;INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q>=$A74);INT('Sheet1'!$Q:$Q<=EOMONTH($A74;0));1/('Sheet1'!K:K))
```

Any suggestions how I could do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `1/'Sheet1'!K:K`

Answer (score 0):

The error is presumably caused by dividing by zero for blanks in column K. If you restrict the range to only the rows with data your formula may work as it stands if there are no zeroes or blanks in the column K range.

Alternatively try using `IFERROR` and ideally restricting the range, e.g. restricted to 1,000 rows

`=SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!J$2:J$1000="Example")*('Sheet1'!M$2:M$1000=F$73)*('Sheet1'!$Q$2:$Q$1000>=$A74)*('Sheet1'!$Q$2:$Q$1000<=EOMONTH($A74;0));'Sheet1'!G$2:G$1000;'Sheet1'!N$2:N$1000;IFERROR(1/'Sheet1'!K$2:K$1000,0))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>